# What is the fastest method for checking for duplicates in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap, set, duplicates

Using a dictionary seems ideal.

e.g.:

```
history = {}
for i in collection:
    if i not in history:
        history[i] = None
        # fancy computation here
```

Would using the set() type be just as fast; set() would not require me to add silly None values to the hash keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should use a set.

---

> Would using the set() type be just as fast;

No, it won't be just as fast. It will be *faster*.

---

**Update**

Some people have posted benchmarks showing that set is slower than dict. I think this is a bit surprising since they basically have the same underlying implementation except that set is simpler. I think that I have found the reason for the slowness:

```
def set_way():
    my_set = set()
    my_set_add = my_set.add   # remember the method
    for ele in x:
        if ele not in my_set:
            my_set_add(ele)   # call the method directly
```

Results:

```
dict time : 1.896939858077399
set time : 1.8587076107880456
```

Set is now slightly faster, as expected.

Comment: Why faster? Checking for a key in a dictionary takes constant time, is it the same exact algorithm for sets?

Comment: @Ramin: Yes, sets use hashes too. The items in a set must be hashable.

Comment: @Ramin The set implementation is almost exactly the same as the `dict` implementation.

Comment: @MarkByers what if the list contains some `unhashable` types like `lists,set` etc?

Comment: Well, a set does not need to allocate memory for a value, it has only a key, so it should be faster and use less memory.

Comment: This benchmark appears to be flawed. I consistently get completely different results.

Comment: @thg435: The inputs are randomly generated.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries seem to be faster.

```
import timeit
import random as rn

x  = [rn.choice(xrange(10000)) for i in xrange(1000)]

def set_way():
    my_set = set()
    for ele in x:
        if ele in my_set:
            return True
        else:
            my_set.add(ele)
    else:
        return False

def dict_way():
    dicto = {}
    for ele in x:
        if ele in dicto:
            return True
        else:
            dicto[ele] = None
    else:
        return False



num = 10000

set_time = timeit.timeit(set_way, number = num)
print 'set time :', set_time
dict_time = timeit.timeit(dict_way, number = num)
print 'dict time :', dict_time
```

Result:

```
set time : 0.619757678699
dict time : 0.466664548148
```

Comment: set is slower? Surprising... Do you have any explanation for that?

Comment: I am surprised as well. Perhaps adding to set is slower than adding to dict? I am curious to know what the explanation is myself.

Comment: +1 for posting the surprising performance measurements. See my updated answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Dicts are faster, but only marginally:

```
import timeit

setup = """
x = range(10000)
s = set(range(5000))
d = dict.fromkeys(range(5000))
"""

print '# set', timeit.timeit('for i in x: z = i in s', setup, number=1000)
print '# dic', timeit.timeit('for i in x: z = i in d', setup, number=1000)

# set 1.18897795677
# dic 1.1489379406
```

Nevertheless, unless performance is absolutely critical, you should use sets for the sake of readability.

Of course, as your question implies, we're talking about hashable types. Unhashable types, like containers, would require other techniques.

For the sake of completeness, here are benchmarks of different modification methods:

```
import timeit

setup = """
x = range(10000)
s = set(range(5000))
d = dict.fromkeys(range(5000))

add_method = s.add
"""

print '# set-add     ', timeit.timeit('for i in x: s.add(i)', setup, number=1000)
print '# set-closure ', timeit.timeit('for i in x: add_method(i)', setup, number=1000)
print '# dict []     ', timeit.timeit('for i in x: d[i]=None', setup, number=1000)
print '# d.setdefault', timeit.timeit('for i in x: d.setdefault(i)', setup, number=1000)

# set-add      1.96829080582
# set-closure  1.2261030674
# dict []      0.982795000076
# d.setdefault 2.27355480194
```

`dict[i]` is the fastest, but this time it's no surprise, because no function call is involved.

Comment: your test does something different than the question. You do not ADD to the set/dict incrementally.

Comment: @thg435, have you run the code enough times to get dict outperform set consistently? Timing algorithms is not a good method for checking speed.

Comment: @schlenk: "add" code doesn't matter much for this question and doesn't affect timings.

Comment: @thg435 "add" matters a lot when it comes to resizing the hash table and changing it. In your example you have the optimal case to know the final size of the table and have it allocated in one step.